# Hostname resolution fails when running docker build from a docker container

Tags: networking, docker, redhat, rhel, docker-compose

We are running a Jenkins CI server from a docker container, started with docker-compose. The Jenkins server is running some jobs which are pulling projects from git and building docker containers the standard way executing `docker build .` on them. To be able to use docker inside the docker container we are mounting over `/var/run/docker.sock` with docker-compose to the Jenkins container.

Some of the Dockerfile-s we are trying to build there are downloading files from our fileserver (3rd party installation images for example). Such a Dockerfile command looks like `RUN curl -o xx.zip http://fileserver/xx-1.2.3.zip`.

The `fileserver` hostname gets resolved through the `/etc/hosts` file and it resolves to the host's public IP which runs the Jenkins CI server. The docker-compose config for the Jenkins container also includes the `extra_hosts` parameter pointing the `fileserver` to the host's public IP.

The problem is that building the docker container with Jenkins running in it's own container fails with a plain `Unknown host: fileserver` message. If I enter the Jenkins container via `docker exec -it <id>`, I can execute the same `curl` command and it resolves the host, but if I try to run `docker build .` there which tries to run the same curl command, it fails to resolve the host.

Our host is an RHEL and I failed to reproduce the problem on my desktop Arch Linux so I suspect it's something redhat-specific issue (again).

Answer (score 2):

Add  --network=host, so that the build env will use the host machine domain resolution.

```
docker build --network=host foo/bar:latest .
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker builds don't happen on the machine issuing the command (your jenkins container, in this case) - they happen on the machine with the Docker Engine.  This means that your Jenkins machine tars up the source directory and ships it back to the parent machine for the build to happen.  So, check if the curl command works from the parent machine, not the Jenkins container.

Comment: The host can resolve and reach the `fileserver` host perfectly, it's one of its aliases in it's own /etc/hosts file pointing to one of the external IP addresses (so not to 127.0.0.1)

Comment: if it helps, the host is an RedHat Enterprise Linux server. Appearently our setup works elsewhere (on my desktop archlinux for example), but not on this RHEL.. (and yes, I turned SELinux off on it)

Comment: Sorry Kristof- that used up my good ideas :(  I have used jenkins to build images on the host docker daemon with an ubuntu host, but I haven't messed with RHEL too much.